# Newton's method for square root recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations

Here is a screenshot from the book. Can you help me with understanding the last line with this approximation? I don't understand how it follows from the formula. Where the denominator has gone?:)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The denominator is
$b_{n-1}+\alpha$.
Since
$b_n \to \alpha$,
this tends to
$2\alpha$.

Therefore
$b_n
\approx \frac{b_{n-1}^2}{4\alpha}
$.

Your reference wanted to show that
$b_n$ converges *quadratically*
to $\sqrt{\beta}$,
and ignored the approximate constant
of
$\frac1{4\sqrt{\beta}}$.
The convergence is still quadratic
no matter what constant is there
in $b_n \approx c b_{n-1}^2$,
but I can see why you were confused.

Comment: Great! Thank you. Looks like mr. Sedgewick skipped half of the reasoning. :)

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n \to \sqrt{\beta} = \alpha$, then $b_n = a_n - \alpha \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  So the recurrence simplifies to $$b_n \approx \frac{b_{n-1}^2}{2\alpha},$$ which you should read as a recurrence on the *deviation* of $a_n$ from $\alpha$:  the size of that deviation decreases quadratically with each additional step; that is to say, the precision of the approximation roughly doubles for each iteration.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I didn't realize that the sign of approximate equality was used instead of proportionality sign. :)